# Unity VS Postsharp in AOP

Tags: c#, aop

All we know that Unity and Postsharp both can be used to Interception(AOP).

But I have done some test with them, AOP perform of Postsharp is more faster than Unity, about treble.

Is it meaning that I should ignore AOP function of Unity directly?

Comment: Voting to close because your question is subjective.  But my subjective opinion is yes.  Using interception for AOP *works*, but it makes it very difficult to understand and debug the code.  See any Java magic-injection-convention-based framework.  On the other side of this argument, updates to Unity are free for commercial use.  Whereas PostSharp has more or less gone to a licensed model.  It depends on what you're trying to accomplish, though - creating proxies of classes is a very good way to solve certain problems (look at the entity framework's lazy loading off POCOs).